# How to terminate complicated queries to database from python?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to integrate `MS-SQL` with `pandas dataframe` over python library `SqlAlchemy`.

Ther's nice way to do this by:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

conn_string= 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}; SERVER='+server_name+'; DATABASE='+db+'; Trusted_Connection=yes'

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
        conn_string)
engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params, deprecate_large_types=False)


df = pd.read_sql(query, engine , parse_dates=date_columns)
```

and i get `pd.DataFrame df`. Nice!

But when my task is to run difficult queries i want to be sure that what i do is under my control.

I would like to write complicated script with joins and sub-querys. And it seems like there's no way to cancel them.

Kill sesssion ID doesn't sound good enough. I would call it `dirty` way. And I'm not aware of my session id from python.

I'm thinking about using `threading` lib

```
def foo():
    smth, that kills my query




t = Threading.Timer(30, foo)
t.start()
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine , parse_dates=date_columns)
t.cancel()
```

Generally, the question is - what should i put in foo so that after 30 sec i would be sure i have tried to kill or even more - 'to be sure i've killed' my session. (ofc if my query is still running after 30 secs)

It would be nice to have such `red button` from `sql server managment studio` and ability to know, if it worked as it should.

[image]

Also I would be happy to look at any recomendations to implement such functionality as:

```
"
--------------------
Block of T-SQL
--------------------

select (.......) 


into pandas.dataframe or into os.open('table.csv', 'wb') or excel-files 


from (....)"
```

from python.

Having `block of T-SQL` and   `select (......) from (......)` as pythong strings.

with the ability to terminate my interactions with DB in thread (or smth like that but with python).

and `Block of T-Sql` commited in my db and result of `sql-select which relies on what was done in T-SQL block` in `DataFrame` variable or `csv(excel)` on my local machine.

If you know how to do this in PG, MySQL or other DBs - feel free to share what are your best practises, as i found no solution for them too. I'm talking about selecting from `complicated mix of tables` (when db isn't ready to give parts of results soon after start.

Comment: You can add some start time and compare against current date time and get the mins.. and if it exceeds just add throw exception..I think it might work that way as well

Comment: For SQL-Server using `kill` *is* the clean way of doing this.

Comment: For kill user must have permission to alter any connection. It is not good idea to grant this for such purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about MS SQL but with psycopg2 this works for me. Should work with cx_Oracle as well

```
from threading import Timer
        
with engine.connect() as connection:
  timeout = Timer(MAX_EXECUTION_TIME, lambda: connection.connection.connection.cancel())
  timeout.start()
  r = connection.execute(stmt).freeze()
  timeout.cancel()
    
df = pd.DataFrame(r().all(), columns=r().first().keys())
```